# How to hide group column display in report viewer report in mvc 4

Tags: reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I have display SSRS report using report viewer in MVC 4 application. In SSRS report when I execute that report on report server it display group column on left side of report means extra column is added on left side of report showing on which field group by is created for that report. So same report is displaying on report viewer.
     Please tell me how to hide that group column from report or display report without displaying that group column.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Column Visibility property. This can be based on an expression, which can refer to a Parameter value.

Comment: where should I set visibility in .rdlc file or in report viewer?

Comment: I have set visibility to hide for group in rdlc file then also it is showing me group column

Comment: You probably need to set Column Visibility, not Group.  Right-click the column heading and choose Column Visibility.